# Kendo Calendar month template - return name of class from outside function

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, calendar

I'm using Kendo Calendar and I have to customize month template: [Official Kendo Reference](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/template)

The problem is when I want return name of class or custom style from external function. For example:

```
$("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
                    month: {
                        // template for dates in month view
                        content: '<div class="' + '#getClass(data)#' + '">#=data.value #</div>'
                    },
                    footer: false
                });

function getClass(data) {
    //do some calculation
    return "class-name";
}
```

But when I use above code returning class isn't show on the template.

Is there any solution for solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like:

```
content: '<div class="' + '#=getClass(data.value)#' + '">#=data.value #</div>'
```